# Integrate $ \int \frac{1}{1 + x^3}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$ \int \frac{1}{1 + x^3}dx  $$

**Attempt:**

I added and subtracted $x^3$ in the numerator but after a little solving I can't get through.

Comment: Start by doing partial-fraction-decomposition on it, then do some variable substitutions

Comment: Notice that by adding $x^{3}$ in the numerator and denominator, you are changing the fraction, which is not allowed.

Comment: @K.Jiang I made a typo. What if I just add and subtract $x^3$ in the numerator?

Comment: @R.Rankin I tried by partial fractions but I am stuck somewhere in between

Comment: It would benefit you if you included your work so that others can proofread it and give you corrections or suggestions.

Comment: You need to solve it by partial fractions, but the process gets very complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{1+x^3}\,dx
&=\int\frac{1-x^2+x^2}{1+x^3}\,dx\\
&=\int\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^3}\,dx+\int\frac{x^2}{1+x^3}\,dx\\
&=\int\frac{1-x}{1-x+x^2}\,dx+\frac13\ln\left(1+x^3\right)+C\\
&=\int\frac{1-(u+1/2)}{1-(u+1/2)+(u+1/2)^2}\,du+\frac13\ln\left(1+x^3\right)+C\\
&=\int\frac{1/2-u}{3/4+u^2}\,du+\frac13\ln\left(1+x^3\right)+C\\
&=\frac12\int\frac{1}{3/4+u^2}\,du-\int\frac{u}{3/4+u^2}\,du+\frac13\ln\left(1+x^3\right)+C\\
&=\frac12\frac{1}{\sqrt{3/4}}\arctan\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{3/4}}\right)-\frac12\ln\left(3/4+u^2\right)+\frac13\ln\left(1+x^3\right)+C\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{x-1/2}{\sqrt{3/4}}\right)-\frac12\ln\left(1-x+x^2\right)+\frac13\ln\left(1+x^3\right)+C\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: There's a mistake here somewhere, I'm sure.

Comment: Found the mistake. Coefficient of $\arctan$.

Comment: What's the intuition that leads you to the substitution $x=u+\frac12$?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs It's to complete the square in the denominator, removing the linear term from the denominator.

Comment: That's cool. It's different from how I usually think about completing the square. I like it.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs $x\mapsto x+c$ is a horizontal shift. So you can always shift a parabola like $1-x+x^2$ left or right until its axis of symmetry is at $x=0$, and that means no linear term. It's extra nice for integration because there's no effect on the $dx$.

Answer (score 7):

Does this help?

$\dfrac{1}{x^3+1} = \dfrac{1}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)} = \dfrac13\left(\dfrac{1}{x+1} - \dfrac{x-2}{x^2-x+1}\right)$

Can you integrate it from there?

The integral of the second part is a little tricky. Note that:

$\dfrac13\left(\dfrac{x-2}{x^2-x+1}\right) = \dfrac16\left(\dfrac{2x-4}{x^2-x+1}\right)= \dfrac16\left(\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1} - \dfrac{3}{x^2-x+1}\right)$

$=\dfrac16\left(\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1} - \dfrac{3}{\left(x-\frac12\right)^2 + \frac34}\right)$

That first integral is a $u$-substitution, and the second uses the arctangent function.

Comment: Yes. thank you.

Comment: Um... this doesn't fix the problem. How can we integrate that second part? A substitution will not work.

Comment: I've added some more steps to show how that's handled. :)

Comment: Great! Looks nice!

Answer (score 4):

I thought it might be instructive to show how we can evaluate the more general integral $I_n(x)$ given by

$$I_n(x)=\int \frac{1}{1+x^n}\,dx$$

for $n\ge 1$

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354106/what-is-the-integration-of-int-1-x2n-1dx/1354485#1354485), I provided a step-by-step presentation that showed

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int\frac{1}{x^n+1}dx=-\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac12 x_{kr}\log(x^2-2x_{kr}x+1)-x_{ki}\arctan\left(\frac{x-x_{kr}}{x_{ki}}\right)\right)+C'} \tag 1
$$

where $x_{kr}$ and $x_{ki}$ are respectively, given by

$$x_{kr}=\text{Re}\left(x_k\right)=\cos \left(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{n}\right) \tag 2$$

$$x_{ki}=\text{Im}\left(x_k\right)=\sin \left(\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{n}\right) \tag 3$$

Using $(1)$-$(3)$ with $n=3$, we find that

$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^3}\,dx=-\frac16 \left(\log(x^2-x+1)-\log(x^2+2x+1)\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C$$

Simplifying, we obtain

$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^3}\,dx=-\frac16 \log(x^2-x+1)+\frac13\log(x+1)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 2):

You can factor the denominator using the formula $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$, and in our case $a=x$ and $b=1$

$$\int \dfrac{1}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)} dx$$

Assume  $\dfrac{1}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)} = \dfrac {A}{x+1} + \dfrac {Bx+C}{x^2-x+1} $

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can do it from here. Thanks.

Comment: It turns out that this does not fix the problem - the second partial fraction cannot be integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a roundabout way.
Let $$I:=\int\frac1{1+x^3}dx, J:=\int\frac x{1+x^3}dx,$$
then

$$I+J=\int\frac {1+x}{1+x^3}dx=\int\frac 1{1-x+x^2}dx=\int\frac1{\left(x-\frac1{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}dx=\frac2{\sqrt3}\arctan\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}+C,$$

$$I-J=\int\frac{1-x}{1+x^3}dx=\int\frac1{1+x}dx-\int\frac{x^2}{1+x^3}dx=\ln\lvert1+x\rvert-\frac1{3}\ln\lvert 1+x^3\rvert+C,$$
solving the above equations yields
$$I=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}+\frac1{2}\ln\lvert1+x\rvert-\frac1{6}\ln\lvert1+x^3\rvert+C,$$
$$J=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}-\frac1{2}\ln\lvert1+x\rvert+\frac1{6}\ln\lvert1+x^3\rvert+C.$$