# $\int\frac{x^n}{1+x^m}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> How do I get a closed form of $$\int\frac{x^n}{1+x^m}dx$$

Background: There were many times that, when I put an integral of the form: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^n}{1+x^m}dx$$in Wolfram Alpha, it gives the indefinite integral too. So I wonder if there is a closed form expression for this indefinite integral.

I know that when $n=m-1$ we easily obtain $\frac{1}{m}\ln(1+x^m)+C$, but other than that I don't know how to obtain the general form. Integration by parts would be too tedious.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx Related

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closed form for $ \int_0^\infty {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{1 + {x^m}}}dx }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx)

Comment: That link deals with a definite integral from $0$ to $\infty$.  Here OP is asking about the indefinite integral.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I know, in fact I'm not saying it's a dupe, it's just related

Comment: No problem. I was just asking.

Comment: The wording of the question is potentially misleading. The display equation is a definite integral, but the following statement refers to "this indefinite integral". It would make the question easier to interpret if the indefinite integral were stated explicitly in another display equation.

Comment: For the special case $a, b \in \Bbb N$, you can find an explicit form in terms of elementary functions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409312/evaluating-int-fracxb1xadx-for-a-b-in-bbb-n?noredirect=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The antiderivative can be written in terms of the Lerch Phi function.

$$\frac{x^{n +1} \Phi \! \left(-x^{m}, 1, \frac{n +1}{m}\right)}{m}$$

This can also be written as a hypergeometric function:

$$\frac{x^{n +1} {}_{2}F_{1}\left(1,\frac{n +1}{m};\frac{m +n +1}{m};-x^{m}\right)}{n +1}
$$

I think that's the best you can do if you want a "closed form" in general.
For particular positive integers $m$ and $n$ you can get an "elementary" (but possibly messy) antiderivative by expanding the integrand in partial fractions.

Comment: There is also an incomplete beta function [conversion](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/03/0006/) in terms of $B_z(a,0)$