# Elementary solution to $ \int \frac{1}{x^5+1} \, dx $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, radicals, partial-fractions

Since [the original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831067/solve-indefinite-integral-int-frac1x51-dx) is heavily downvoted, I'm not sure if the moderators will delete it before I can post my answer.

---

Here's my attempt:

Following JG's remarks, we have

$$ x^5 + 1 = \frac14(x+1)(2x^2 + x(\sqrt5 - 1) + 2)(2x^2 - x(\sqrt5 - 1) + 2) $$

Then by [partial fractions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fraction%2C+4%2F%28%28x%2B1%29%282x%5E2+%2B+x%28sqrt5+-+1%29+%2B+2%29%282x%5E2+-+x+%28sqrt5+-+1%29+%2B+2%29%29), we have $$ \dfrac1{x^5 + 1} = \dfrac4{(x+1)(2x^2 + x(\sqrt5 - 1) + 2)(2x^2 - x(\sqrt5 - 1) + 2)} $$ is equal to $$ \dfrac2{5+\sqrt5} \cdot \dfrac1{x+1} -\dfrac{4\sqrt5}{(\sqrt5 - 1)(5+\sqrt5)} \cdot \dfrac x{2x^2 - x(\sqrt5 - 1) + 2} + \dfrac4{(\sqrt5-1)(5+\sqrt5)} \cdot \dfrac{x + \sqrt5 + 1}{2x^2 + x(\sqrt5 - 1) + 2}$$

What's left is to apply $ \int \dfrac1{x^2+a^2} \, dx = \frac1a \tan^{-1} (\frac xa) + C$ and $ \int \dfrac{1}{x^2-a^2}\, dx = -\frac 1a \tanh^{-1} (\frac xa) + C$.

---

Obviously all the calculations above are fairly tedious. Is there a(another) way to evaluate this indefinite integral?

To clarify, I'm not interested to see ANY roots of unity ($\omega $) in the final result.

Naturally, I'm also interested if there's other approach is applicable for the indefinite integral of $\frac1{x^n + 1}$ for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: Well the answer can be seen: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28x%5E5%2B1%29   The point is: it IS complex and therefore the calculations ARE tedious. So you'll have to do the work which you already started. It's going to get even worse for larger $n$ ...

Comment: If you don't mind infinite series, $1/(x^5+1)=1-x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}-\cdots$ and you can integrate term-by-term.

Comment: In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999869/evaluate-int-frac11xndx-for-n-in-mathbb-r/1999967#1999967), I developed a closed form solution to the indefinite integral $\int \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.  In that answer, I referenced my answer posted [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354106/what-is-the-primitive-function-of-int-1-x2n-1dx/1354485#1354485), which was relevant for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you Mark and Arctic! They certainly helped!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, integrate $g(x,\phi)=\frac{2\phi x-2}{x^2-2\phi x+1}$
\begin{align}
I(x,\phi) &= \int g(x,\phi)dx 
=\phi\ln\left(x^2-2\phi x+1\right)
-2\sqrt{1-\phi^2}
\tan^{-1}\frac{x-\phi}{\sqrt{1-\phi^2}}
\end{align}
Then, with $\phi_{\pm} = \frac{1\pm\sqrt5}{4}$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{1+x^5}dx
&=\frac15 \int \left(\frac1{x+1}- g(x,\phi_+)
- g(x,\phi_-) \right) dx\\
&=\frac15\left[\ln(x+1)-I(x,\phi_+)-I(x,\phi_-)\right] + C
\end{align}