# Has this been solved: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{2n}+1}$?

Tags: calculus

It gets complicated pretty quickly.

For $n = 1$
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx = \arctan(x)_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$
For $n=2$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4+1}dx = \left[\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\log{\frac{x^2+\sqrt2x+1}{x^2-\sqrt2x+1}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\arctan{\frac{\sqrt2x}{1-x^2}}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$
Is there a formula for all $n$ and if so where can I find it.

Comment: As far as I know, for $n$ unspecified, you need [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to comput it.

Comment: Some MSE thoughts here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354106/what-is-the-primitive-function-of-int-1-x2n-1dx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, we have the following integral:

$$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}:=\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{1+x^{2\text{n}}}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Where $\text{n}\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let's first observe that the integrand is an even function, this implies:

$$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}=2\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^{2\text{n}}}\space\text{d}x\tag2$$

Now, we can split the integral:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^{2\text{n}}}\space\text{d}x=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^{2n}}\space\text{d}x+\int_0^1\frac{x^{2\text{n}-2}}{1+x^{2\text{n}}}\space\text{d}x\tag3$$

And it is not very hard to see that we can use an infinite series to rewrite the integrands:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^{2\text{n}}}\space\text{d}x=\int_0^1\left(1-x^{2\text{n}}+x^{4\text{n}}-x^{6\text{n}}+\dots\right)\space\text{d}x+$$
$$\int_0^1\left(x^{2\text{n}-2}-x^{4\text{n}-2}+x^{6\text{n}-2}+\dots\right)\space\text{d}x\tag4$$

I will let you prove the fact:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^{2\text{n}}}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2\text{n}}\sum_{\text{k}\space\in\space\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^\text{k}}{\text{k}+\frac{1}{2\text{n}}}=\frac{\pi}{2\text{n}}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2\text{n}}\right)\tag5$$

The last step uses the result from "An Infinite Alternating Harmonic Series".

> So, in the end we end up with:
>
> $$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}:=\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{1+x^{2\text{n}}}\space\text{d}x=\frac{2\pi}{2\text{n}}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2\text{n}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{\text{n}}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2\text{n}}\right)$$

Comment: how did you obtain step 3. Thanks

Comment: @StanislasCASTELLANA Try to look at the second integral and change the bounds back to $1$ and $\infty$. Now think of a clever substitution, I know you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Use the known result

$$\int_0^\infty \frac {x^{a-1}}{x^m +1} = \frac\pi m \csc\frac{\pi a}m $$

Comment: Is there a proof to this?

Comment: @StanislasCASTELLANA - See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx?noredirect=1&lq=1