# How to calculate this infinite series?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{3n-2}$
By expanding $\dfrac{1}{1+x^3}$. I get a wrong answer$\dfrac{\ln2}{3}+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{18}$.Why?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592898/

Comment: How should we know? By integrating $\frac{x}{1+x^3}$ over $(0,1)$ you should get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$xS=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac {x^{3n-3}}{3n-2}=\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n-3}dx=?$$

Here $x^3=-1$